# checking if value matches mode and iterating through a loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create a loop where the loop looks at each value. If the value in a column equals the most common result in the column (the mode), it returns 1 else it should return 0. Here is the code I have so far. I would really appreciate the help:

```
a= []

for i in AnswerColumns['Answer1']:
    if int(AnswerColumns['Answer1'][i]) ==  int(AnswerColumns['Answer1'].mode()):
        a.append(1)
    else: 
        a.append(0)
```

Comment: isn't it just `AnswerColumns['Answer1'] == AnswerColumns['Answer1'].mode()[0]`?

Comment: If you are using pandas, you can leverage in-built methods of the library. This is considered best practice because these functions are generally implemented in a very optimized way so that we don't have to write custom code for it.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You're already determining the value in two places; simply return it.  BTW, we're not clear on how you plan to return it, since this fragment is not inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hoang pointed you in the right direction, if you need to save it as integers  and not a boolean mask do:

```
a = (AnswerColumns['Answer1'] == AnswerColumns['Answer1'].mode()[0]).astype(int).to_list()
```